# How can I create a bluetooth headset client?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, headset

I have a raspberry pi with a speaker and a microphone attached.  I'd like this to mimic a bluetooth headset for my cell phone.  Basically the same way my beats headphones do... it would connect to my phone via bluetooth, stream audio from the mic to my phone, and play the phones audio over the speakers.

I haven't been able to find many resources online about creating a bluetooth client.  Is this possible?  It seems like it should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

On iOS you would need to apply for their BlueTooth development program. They only let businesses that pass their review develop Bluetooth accessories for iOS devices.  (Note the Bluetooth low energy devices don't require a license, just streaming devices like headsets.)

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  Accessories that implement standard Bluetooth profiles, such as handsfree (HFP) don't need to be MFi certified.  This question is asking how to make a RPi act as an HFP peripheral. See https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2 and https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204387